# Odoo 10 : Module imports

Tags: python, class, import, module, odoo

I created a new module called **logs** which structure is :

```
logs
  |_models
        |_models.py
```

In this models.py I have a class :

```
import logging

class Log():

  def __init__(self):
    self.x=5
    .
    .
    .




  def warning(self,msg):
    print(msg)
```

Now I want to call this **warning** function from other module called **contacts** which structure is also :

```
contacts
  |_models
        |_models.py
```

in this models.py I import my module **logs** like this :

```
from ... import logs
```

and i call **warning** function like this :

```
log = logs.models.models.Log()
        log.warning("YAYYYYY")
```

This works fine. But I would like to have a smaller line instead of  **logs.models.models.Log()** .Something like **log=Log()** . What change should i do in the code?

**Info** : Both modules are in addons folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
from ...logs.models.models import Log
```

The official docs for this are at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt .